# not able to get values from Map - getting values as object reference

Tags: java, java-8, jackson

I have a Map<String,Object> which contains a json value - not able to serialize/deserialize it.

JSON:

```
{
    "createdDate": "Jul 05, 2019 05:10:51 PM",
    "createdUserId": 16,
    "lastModifiedDate": "Jul 10, 2019 11:48:58 AM",
    "lastModifiedUserId": 16,
    "value": "Mahindra",
    "key": "oemName"
}
```

not able to write it as JSON string.
Values in it are containing object reference instead of values  as below -

```
{createdDate=java.lang.Object@1682b904, createdUserId=java.lang.Object@3cd68604, lastModifiedDate=java.lang.Object@5d8c47e2, lastModifiedUserId=java.lang.Object@42d07479, value=java.lang.Object@4119bfbe, key=java.lang.Object@4977f73f}
```

When tried to write as JSON -

```
     Map<String, Object> additionalInfo;
     private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
     objectMapper.writeValueAsString(additionalInfo);
```

Getting Exception-

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class java.lang.Object and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["createdDate"])

[image]

Comment: I think your problem is in the code that creates the map, not the code that tries to output it.  It looks like the map is created with `java.lang.Object` values, rather than String values.

Comment: I'm receiving the value through POJO which as a variable as - private Map<String, Object> additionalInfo; and converting to JAVA pojo.

Comment: `java.lang.Object` is just an empty object. You can declare map as `Map<String, Object> additionalInfo` but you should put values like they are: `additionalInfo.put("createdDate", "Jul 05, 2019 05:10:51 PM")` not `additionalInfo.put("createdDate", new Object())`. Every object in `Java` extends `java.lang.Object` and in runtime you should see it real class value.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the GSON lib solved this issue.
Updating from 1.7.1 to 2.8.2 solved my issue.